# Forward transformed event from Observable directly to BehaviourSubject

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactivex

I'm really really new to Rx and RxSwift and I'm trying to learn by reading and doing at the same time, so maybe this question makes you laugh. Please, excuse me in advance :P

I have this architecture:

```
MatchView -> MatchViewModel -> P2PSession -> MCSession+Rx
```

I've made a Reactive extension of `MCSession` to make session state changes an observable:

```
var didChangeState: Observable<(MCPeerID, MCSessionState)> {
    return RxMCSessionDelegateProxy.proxy(for: base).didChangeStateSubject.asObservable()
}
```

Then, I have another object, `P2PSession`, subscribed to that observable in order to transform the received event to emit it to a `BehaviorSubject<MCPeerID?>` to be observed by my `MatchViewModel`, that will transform it to emit to a `Variable<String>` to be shown in a label.

Maybe that chaining is totally ridiculous but here is the complete (but simplified) thing:

**P2PSession**

```
var connectedPeer: BehaviorSubject<MCPeerID?> = BehaviorSubject(value: nil)

mcSession.rx.didChangeState
    .subscribe(onNext: { self.connectedPeer.onNext($0.0) })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

**MatchViewModel**

```
var peerName = Variable("")

p2pSession.connectedPeer.asObservable()
    .map({ $0?.displayName ?? "None" })
    .subscribe(onNext: { self.peerName.value = $0 })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

**MatchView**

```
viewModel.peerName.asDriver()
    .drive(peerLabel.rx.text)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

It works, as a peer connects, a delegate method is called in the `RxMCSessionDelegateProxy` and data travels through the chain until it is shown in the label.

But I think that could be made way more elegant. Is it possible to forward a transformed event from an observable to a subject without making the subscription to the first observable to transform and inject the value to the subject/variable? (as I make in `P2PSession`). I don't know if I've explained myself correctly but I think that's possible with `flatMap` but I'm not getting it correctly, maybe I need the `subscribe` anyway and I'm trying to do stupid things.

Thank you so much, I need your help!

Comment: Do you really need a subject? Because this can easily be done by chaining observables using map. Subjects (Variables are subjects) add state and you are only mapping from one type to another.

Comment: @FelipeCypriano Maybe I can change my `BehaviorSubject` with a `Variable` but I'll have the same problem, right? Would you please show me the code with your solution? Thanks.

Comment: If you notice the correct answer is doesn't rely on subjects. You might be exposing readwrite access to your classes internals w/o needing/wanting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expose the connected peer via an `Observable`, and the peer name through a `Driver`:

```
let connectedPeer: Observable<MCPeerID?>
connectedPeer = mcSession.rx.didChangeState.map { $0.0 }

let peerName: Driver<String>
peerName = p2pSession.connectedPeer.map { $0.displayName ?? "None" }.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: "None")

viewModel.peerName.drive(peerLabel.rx.text).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with the `connectedPeer` but with `peerName` it errors:

`Cannot convert call result type 'Observable<_>' to expected type 'SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, String>!'`. I can't find a solution T_T

Comment: Well, using `peerName = p2pSession.connectedPeer.map{ $0.displayName }.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: "None")` it works, but I don0t know if it is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added the conversion.